# How to have 3x3 collection of pages in one page?

Tags: packages

The document contains 999 pages. 
I would like to have for instance nine pages as `3x3` in one page. 
I want to compile the big `.tex` file into the setting `2x2`, `3x3`, `9x9`, ...

How can you have a collection of pages in one page?

Comment: I assume you mean to include pages of the 999-page `.pdf` document into another LaTeX document?

Comment: No. Just compile the tex file into setting 3x3, for instance, or 9x9 etc.

Comment: The other stuff would be easier ;-) But I think `geometry` package will be involved

Comment: package `pdfpages`  used in a wrapper document.

Comment: @Johannes_B: That's what I had in mind first!

Comment: If you want the entire document in 3x3 format, using 'print to file' with that option set might work as well as a latex-specific approach

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's the first thought I had, perhaps it's usable anyway:

The `nup=3x3` option will provide this layout.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}

\includepdf[nup=3x3,pages=-]{myoversizeddocument}

\end{document}
```

`myoversizeddocument.tex` as the principal document (the `pgffor` package is only to make a number of pages easily)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}

\foreach \x in {1,...,99} {
\includegraphics[scale=3]{beeduck}
\clearpage
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution using `pgfpages` (by default there is 2 on 1, 4 on 1, 8 on 1 and 16 on 1).

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesdeclarelayout{9 on 1}
{
  \edef\pgfpageoptionheight{\the\paperheight} 
  \edef\pgfpageoptionwidth{\the\paperwidth}
  \edef\pgfpageoptionborder{0pt}
}
{
  \pgfpagesphysicalpageoptions
  {%
    logical pages=9,%
    physical height=\pgfpageoptionheight,%
    physical width=\pgfpageoptionwidth%
  }
  \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{1}
  {%
    border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
    resized width=.33\pgfphysicalwidth,%
    resized height=.33\pgfphysicalheight,%
    center=\pgfpoint{.165\pgfphysicalwidth}{.825\pgfphysicalheight}%
  }%
  \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{2}
  {%
    border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
    resized width=.33\pgfphysicalwidth,%
    resized height=.33\pgfphysicalheight,%
    center=\pgfpoint{.495\pgfphysicalwidth}{.825\pgfphysicalheight}%
  }%
  \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{3}
  {%
    border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
    resized width=.33\pgfphysicalwidth,%
    resized height=.33\pgfphysicalheight,%
    center=\pgfpoint{.825\pgfphysicalwidth}{.825\pgfphysicalheight}%
  }%
  \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{4}
  {%
    border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
    resized width=.33\pgfphysicalwidth,%
    resized height=.33\pgfphysicalheight,%
    center=\pgfpoint{.165\pgfphysicalwidth}{.495\pgfphysicalheight}%
  }%
  \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{5}
  {%
    border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
    resized width=.33\pgfphysicalwidth,%
    resized height=.33\pgfphysicalheight,%
    center=\pgfpoint{.495\pgfphysicalwidth}{.495\pgfphysicalheight}%
  }%
  \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{6}
  {%
    border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
    resized width=.33\pgfphysicalwidth,%
    resized height=.33\pgfphysicalheight,%
    center=\pgfpoint{.825\pgfphysicalwidth}{.495\pgfphysicalheight}%
  }%
  \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{7}
  {%
    border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
    resized width=.33\pgfphysicalwidth,%
    resized height=.33\pgfphysicalheight,%
    center=\pgfpoint{.195\pgfphysicalwidth}{.165\pgfphysicalheight}%
  }%
  \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{8}
  {%
    border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
    resized width=.33\pgfphysicalwidth,%
    resized height=.33\pgfphysicalheight,%
    center=\pgfpoint{.495\pgfphysicalwidth}{.165\pgfphysicalheight}%
  }%
  \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{9}
  {%
    border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
    resized width=.25\pgfphysicalwidth,%
    resized height=.25\pgfphysicalheight,%
    center=\pgfpoint{.825\pgfphysicalwidth}{.165\pgfphysicalheight}%
  }%
}

\pgfpagesuselayout{9 on 1}


\usepackage{blindtext}
\title{999 pages}
\author{Me}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\blinddocument
the end
\end{document}
```

Note that `pgfpages` break hyperlink.